# optimize replaces NA with maximum value

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to optimize a value and I keep getting an error that says

`In optimize(my_func, 3:20, tol = 1, maximum = T, comparator = data$changeUP,  :NA/Inf replaced by maximum positive value`

What `NA` value is it replacing? the `NA` in my calculated `xxx` value? How can I make it not do that?

```
data(ttrc)
data<-data.frame(Close=Cl(ttrc),changeUP=ifelse(Cl(ttrc)-Lag(Cl(ttrc))>0,1,0))
colnames(data)<-c("Close","changeUP")
###################################################################################
xxx<-RSI(Cl(data),n=3) #hardcoded one specific value of MA in order to test the optimization of the cutoff
xxx<-lag(xxx)

res<-optimize(my_func,3:20,tol=1,maximum=T,comparator=data$changeUP,calculated_statistic=xxx)
res$maximum
res$objective

my_func<-function(i,comparator,calculated_statistic){
  qq<-as.factor(calculated_statistic<i)
  comparison<-table(data$changeUP==qq,useNA = "no")
  comparison[2]/(comparison[1]+comparison[2])#calculate success rate for the cutoff
}
```

My completed code using loops (still has an odd bug) but this is what I am eventually trying to do with the optimization.

```
data(ttrc)
data<-data.frame(Close=Cl(ttrc),changeUP=ifelse(Cl(ttrc)-Lag(Cl(ttrc))>0,1,0))
colnames(data)<-c("Close","changeUP")
###################################################################################
master_rsi<-lapply(3:20,function(j){ #test every RSI period
  xxx<-RSI(Cl(data),n=j)
  xxx<-lag(xxx)
  cat("indicator parameter=",j,"\n")

  tempdf<-lapply(10:90,function(i){ #test every cutoff point for the values
    qq<-xxx<i
    qq<-as.factor(qq)
    comparison<-table(data$changeUP==qq,useNA = "no")
    pp<-comparison[2]/(comparison[1]+comparison[2])#calculate success rate for the cutoff
    cat(pp)
    pp
  })

  tempdf<-unlist(tempdf)
  rp<-paste0("MA period: ",j," success rate: ",max(tempdf)," cutoff: ",which.max(tempdf)+9,"\n")
  cat(rp)
  rp
})
unlist(master_rsi)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be helpful to force `qq` and `data$changeUP` to be factors with the same levels 0,1:

```
library(quantmod)
data(ttrc)
data<-data.frame(Close=Cl(ttrc),changeUP=ifelse(Cl(ttrc)-Lag(Cl(ttrc))>0,1,0))
colnames(data)<-c("Close","changeUP")
data$changeUP <- factor(data$changeUP, levels=0:1)
###################################################################################
fun <- function(j){ #test every RSI period
  xxx <- RSI(Cl(data),n=j)
  xxx <- lag(xxx)
  cat("indicator parameter=",j,"\n")

  tempdf <- lapply(10:90,function(i){ #test every cutoff point for the values
      qq <- factor(as.numeric(xxx<i), levels=0:1)
      comparison <- table(data$changeUP==qq,useNA = "no")
      pp <- comparison[2]/(comparison[1]+comparison[2])#calculate success rate for the cutoff
      ##cat(i, pp,"\n")
      pp
  })

  tempdf <- unlist(tempdf)
  rp <- paste0("MA period: ",j," success rate: ",max(tempdf)," cutoff: ",which.max(tempdf)+9,"\n")
  cat(rp,"\n")
  rp
}
master_rsi <- lapply(3:20,fun)
unlist(master_rsi)
```